# replace subsequent character if a values of a series contains a specific set of characters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df:
col1      col2         col3
 1       123xy56      pyrxyz 
 3        hcv           P
 xy12      R            T
 5        453xy         Z
 2        lxy6          Q
```

I want to remove everything starts with xy in every column of the data frame. if any value starts with xy then replace that with zero.

The final data frame should look like:

```
col1      col2         col3
 1        123           pyr
 3        hcv           P
 0         R            T
 5        453           Z
 2         l            Q
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all values, not just the ones that start with xy? Also in column 1, you replace xy12 with 0, is that a typo or it is intended?

Comment: This is very unclear, please can you explain  first row in col2

Answer (score 1):

You could use [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) twice:

```
result = df.replace('xy.*', '', regex=True).replace('', 0)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  col1 col2 col3
0    1  123  pyr
1    3  hcv    P
2    0    R    T
3    5  453    Z
4    2    l    Q
```

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient but work

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('xy').str[0]).replace('',0)

Out[386]: 
  col1 col2 col3
0    1  123  pyr
1    3  hcv    P
2    0    R    T
3    5  453    Z
4    2    l    Q
```

Comment: I want to remove everything after xy but you got 12 in 3rd row, it should be zero, if a string starts with xy